In Uno4 applications, where are WebView2 js files stored and how are they accessed?
I have a WebView2 control in my application. A small HTML document is given it to render. Currently it refers to web-based scripts. It's not a given when the app runs that web connectivity will be present. Where in the Uno4/Windows11 application tree do I store the JavaScript file and how do I refer to it in the HTML document?
The method as it stands is
private string TurtleFrameworkPlus(string jsBlock)
{
    return $@"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/real-turtle'></script>" +
             "<canvas id='real-turtle'></canvas>" +
             "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/real-turtle/build/helpers/simple.js'></script>" +
             $"<script type='text/javascript'>{jsBlock}</script>";
        }

However, I'd like to be able to store the two scripts from unpkg.com locally. I've tried putting them in resources but haven't had much success. For example, I've tried
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

var library = resourceLoader.GetString("real-turtle_js");
var simple = resourceLoader.GetString("simple_js");

return $"<script type='text/javascript'>{library}</script>" +
       "<canvas id='real-turtle'></canvas>" +
       $"<script type='text/javascript'>{simple}</script>" +
       $"<script type='text/javascript'>{jsBlock}</script>";

but there appear to issues regarding which ResourceLoader to use and in any case I get COM errors.
